# Probability of no two objects having same number

Tags: probability

Say I have collection of distinct objects and I assign a number to each object from the range 1 to $n^3$ (inclusive).

Here's what I have done:
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Choices }=k=n^{3}\\ 
\text { objects }=n\\
P(\text { No collisicn })=\frac{k}{k}+\frac{k-1}{k}+\frac{k-2}{k} \cdots \cdots \cdot \frac{k-n+2}{k}+\frac{k-n+1}{k} \\
=\frac{k !}{k^n(k-n) !}=\frac{n^{3 !}}{n^{3n}\left(n^{3}-n\right)}
\end{array}

How do I proceed after this ?

Comment: Look up the birthday paradox.

Comment: Clarification requested: are the numbers assigned with or without replacement?  In other words, in the 1st assignment, can you have two objects both assigned the number $(n^3)$?

Comment: While I don't agree with the downvote that your question has attracted, I can at least explain it.  See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) for an explanation.

Comment: @user2661923 objects can get two same numbers so this implies that it is with replacement. if it was without replacement then the porb that two objects gets same number would zero

Comment: Good catch, which I overlooked.  However, I am confused.  What is the relevance of the first assignment of numbers (from $1$ to $n^3$)?  Isn't the question asking the student to ignore the 1st number assigned, and simply consider whether the 2nd number assigned (from $1$ to $n^2$) is distinct for all distinct objects?  If so, do you perceive any difference between this problem and the birthday problem?

Comment: Also, I am assuming that the number of distinct objects is some fixed positive integer $m$, so that the final computation of the probability must be a function of both $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @user2661923. let me phrase it better. the first problem and the second is completely different. In the first case, the number of choices available are n^3. you solve probability first for this case. second problem is the same but the choices has been reduced to n^2. in both case the number of objects (distinct) are n

Comment: @user2661923 I realise you can get the equation for probability using the birthday paradox framework

Comment: Perhaps, with respect to the article that I cited re mathSE protocols, you may consider editing your question to show your work, on both of these problems.  This way, if you make an analytical mistake, a mathSE reviewer may correct your mistake without violating mathSE protocol.  Further, explanations or ambiguity resolutions belong in the (edited) question rather than the comments.

Comment: @user2661923 Fair enough. will make the changes. Thanks

Comment: @user2661923 I simplified the question and updated my working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> \begin{array}{l}
> \text { Choices }=k=n^{3}\\ 
> \text { objects }=n\\
> P(\text { No collisicn })=\frac{k}{k}+\frac{k-1}{k}+\frac{k-2}{k} \cdots \cdots \cdot \frac{k-n+2}{k}+\frac{k-n+1}{k} \\
> =\frac{k !}{k^n(k-n) !}=\frac{n^{3 !}}{n^{3n}\left(n^{3}-n\right)}
> \end{array}

> How do I proceed after this ?

Should be

$$P(\text{no collision}) = \frac{k}{k} \times \frac{k-1}{k} \times \frac{k-2}{k} \times \cdots \times \frac{k-n+2}{k} \times \frac{k-n+1}{k}
$$

$$=\frac{k !}{k^n[(k-n)!]}=\frac{[n^{3}]!}{n^{3n}[\left(n^{3}-n\right)!]} 
.\tag1$$

At this point, it depends on your goal.  If all you want is a closed form expression, (1) above fulfills this, so you are done.  If instead, you want to facilitate calculating this numerically, for a specific value of $n$, either through a calculator or a pc program, then you have two choices:

- If the numbers aren't *too bad*, you can calculate the exact value in a pc program, perhaps using a *big integer* facility, as is provided by Java.
- If a numeric estimate, accurate to 4 or 5 decimal places is sufficient, I strongly recommend using logarithms (i.e. the logarithm of a product equals the sum of the individual logarithms).  PC languages (e.g. Java, C, python, ...) should have canned logarithm routines.

---

**Addendum**

Given $m$ objects and $k$ numbers to select from (i.e. *choices*) without replacement ($m < k$), the standard expression for the probability of no collision is

$$\frac{k !}{k^m[(k-m)!]}.$$

In the standard birthday problem, $k = 365$,
so $\displaystyle p(m) = \frac{365 !}{365^{m}[(365 - m)!]}.$

Then, the classic problem is to compute the minimum value of $m$ such that $p(m) < (1/2).$  As discussed in the answer, this may routinely be computed via logarithms.